# How to do http error handling in Go language

Tags: go, error-handling

I am little confused on how error handling should be done in go. I have read so many posts about it but still am not able to apply them on my structure of code. I am new to go so please help.

There is a main function which handles two apis: api1 and api2

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/offers", api1)
    http.HandleFunc("/getOffersList", api2)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}


func api1(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    validateRequestHeader(w, req, "GET")
    // code here....
}

func api2(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    validateRequestHeader(w, req, "POST")
    //code here....
}

func validateRequestHeader(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, allowedMethod string) {
    // allow cross domain AJAX requests
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if origin := req.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
    }
    // Stop here if its Preflighted OPTIONS request
    if req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }
    if req.Method != allowedMethod {
        response := "Only " + allowedMethod + " requests are allowed"
        http.Error(w, response, http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
}
```

In both `api1` and `api2` , function `validateRequestHeader` is getting called. If this gets true, then in the api1/api2 further code is getting executed which I do not want. How it should be handled?

```
if req.Method != allowedMethod {
        response := "Only " + allowedMethod + " requests are allowed"
        http.Error(w, response, http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
```

Comment: If !validate then return

Comment: @Warrior validateRequestHeader(w, req, "POST") used as value

Comment: The question is what should I return `http.Error(w, response, http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return` here

Comment: Anything to signal the result of validation.

Comment: The idiomatic go way is `validateRequestHeader` method to return an error type and on method invocation to check if `err != nil`. Only in this case to continue.

Comment: There's not a "right" way to do, learn the logic behind it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This blog post](https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/middlewares-golang-best-practices-examples/) goes into some details on how to chain multiple handler functions, which is what you should be doing. That way, you can have a validation handler, a logging handler, an authorization handler, etc etc. and just chain them together.

Essentially

```
func validator(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            if isRequestValid(req) {
                // a valid request is passed on to next handler
                next.ServeHTTP(w, req)
            } else {
                // otherwise, respond with an error
                http.Error(w, "Bad request - Go away!", 400)
            }
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func api1() http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            // api 1 code
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func api2() http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            // api 2 code
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
```

And then chain them up in your `main` function.

```
func main() {
    http.Handler("/offers", validate(api1()))
    http.Handler("/getOffersList", validate(api2()))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: This reply is good, but I'd make it more clear by pointing out that the validator code blocks the chain on errors

Comment: @GianfrancoReppucci I expanded a bit on the validator logic. Is it clearer that it is executed first and determines if the `next` handler will be used?